# How to split all properties of an object into a string delimited by an underscore?

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I have a huge json object with object and properties, and more objects and properties that continues.  I need a recursive way to get all property keys and have them outputted per level

For example:

```
{
    "references":[
        {"id":"00-0031280","origin":"gsis"},
        {"id":"CAR358797","origin":"elias"},
        {"id":"41265","origin":"nflx"}
    ],
    "team":{
        "name":"Raiders",
        "market":"Oakland",
        "alias":"OAK",
        "id":"1c1cec48-6352-4556-b789-35304c1a6ae1"
    },
    "name": "Name",
    "jersey": "08"
}
```

I need to loop within this object somehow and get returned the entire depth of the json object keys 1 by 1, so should return this, each line being outputted from a for loop:

```
references_0_id
references_0_origin
references_1_id
references_1_origin
references_2_id
references_2_origin
team_name
team_market
team_alias
team_id
name
jersey
```

So far I have something like this, but it's not good enough, as it doesn't loop properly...

```
function eachRecursive(obj, aKey)
{
    aKey = aKey === null ? '' : aKey;

    for (var k in obj)
    {
        if (typeof obj[k] == "object" && obj[k] !== null)
        {
            aKey += k + '_';
            eachRecursive(obj[k], aKey);
        }
        else
        {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(k))
            {
                $('.output').append($('<p />').text(aKey + k));
            }
            // might not even need this.
            aKey = '';
        }
    }
}
```

There seems to be something wrong with the output of `aKey`, basically, `aKey` + `k` I thought would give me the result I'm trying to get here, but `aKey` is keeping to much and not being cleared properly.

Can someone please help me with this function? Been trying to get the output to work correctly for awhile now with no luck.

**EDIT

Here is a jsfiddle that demonstrates problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/raob9pbd/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you're continually modifying `aKey` inside a loop, without starting from its initial value when you append the `_`.  You can fix this simply by changing your code to say:

```
eachRecursive(obj[k], aKey + k + '_');
```

and remove the two lines that modify `aKey`

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/a8gb0g5L/

Comment: Hello, thanks, but it needs to loop within all depths of the json object.  This looks like it only loops through 1 depth.

Comment: @SolomonClosson no, it's recursive - it'll go all the way down.

Comment: ah - one bug, though - it incorrectly enumerates the `length` property of arrays.

Comment: Ok, you are right it goes all the way down, but also need to get value where `results.push(current)` is happening.

Comment: @SolomonClosson I've revised this to just show how to fix your own code, instead of my original code that inadvertently included the array's `length` property.

Comment: Thank a Million, exactly what I was missing in the function.  Been scratching my head thinking about it for awhile also.  Wish I could buy you a beer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing `$.map()` , `$.isArray()` , `$.isPlainObject()` , `Object.keys()`

```
var res = $.map(data, function(value, key) {
  if ($.isArray(value)) {
    return $.map(value, function(v, k) {
       return Object.keys(v).map(function(n, i) {
         return key + "_" + k + "_" + n
       })
    }); 
  } 

  if ($.isPlainObject(value)) {
       return Object.keys(value).map(function(n, i) {
         return key + "_" + i + "_" + n
    }); 
  } else {
       return key
  }

});
```

```js
var data = {
    "references":[
        {"id":"00-0031280","origin":"gsis"},
        {"id":"CAR358797","origin":"elias"},
        {"id":"41265","origin":"nflx"}
    ],
    "team":{
        "name":"Raiders",
        "market":"Oakland",
        "alias":"OAK",
        "id":"1c1cec48-6352-4556-b789-35304c1a6ae1"
    },
    "name": "Name",
    "jersey": "08"
}

var res = $.map(data, function(value, key) {
  if ($.isArray(value)) {
    return $.map(value, function(v, k) {
       return Object.keys(v).map(function(n, i) {
         return key + "_" + k + "_" + n
       })
    }); 
  } 

  if ($.isPlainObject(value)) {
       return Object.keys(value).map(function(n, i) {
         return key + "_" + i + "_" + n
    }); 
  } else {
       return key
  }

});

console.log(res)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The solution requires recursion so that it can traverse any depth